# Incorrect Function call Not throwing Error in PYQT

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Why is call to wrong function self.textBrowser.appendkjsdhsk("Finished") is not throwing any error. It silently ignores it.

How to make sure these exception are thrown?
Is this expected behavior?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_XYZ_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, XYZ_MainWindow):
        XYZ_MainWindow.setObjectName("XYZ_MainWindow")
        XYZ_MainWindow.resize(564, 363)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(XYZ_MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralWidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 521, 201))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 40, 80, 22))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        XYZ_MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainToolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(XYZ_MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName("mainToolBar")
        XYZ_MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.retranslateUi(XYZ_MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(XYZ_MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, XYZ_MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        XYZ_MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("XYZ_MainWindow", "XYZ_MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("XYZ_MainWindow", "PushButton"))



import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class Example_1(QMainWindow, Ui_XYZ_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example_1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.event_pushButton_clicked)

    def event_pushButton_clicked(self):
        self.textBrowser.append("*****Started*****")
        self.textBrowser.appendkjsdhsk("Finished")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try: 
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex1 = Example_1()
        ex1.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except:
        print("Done.")
```

This does not even terminates the GUI or program. It continues to work as if that line is not there.

Result after multiple click

[image]

Comment: Your code fails correctly for me with `AttributeError: 'QTextBrowser' object has no attribute 'appendkjsdhsk'`.

Comment: I am running this on spyder 3.0.2 IDE. Is this because of that? New to python and GUI programming so I am not sure. Which IDE you used?

Comment: No IDE. Just Vim, Linux and Python3.6. But I can't imagine any of that would mask an error like this. You did click the button, right?

Comment: @FamousJameous  Yes, I did. Added Image(Result after multiple clicks) also in my post now.

Comment: Yeah, that is odd. I don't know how that could be happening with the code you posted.

Comment: If i run this from command line I get the same error as yours. so it seems to be IDE issue. For now i will test my code by running from command line. Thanks @FamousJameous